# Adding a polygon to a multipolygon column

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a table that contains a multipolygon column.

In my application, I use a view on the table which splits the multipolygon in several polygons:

```
CREATE VIEW myview
AS SELECT a.id,
    ST_SetSRID((st_dump(a.geom)).geom,25832) AS geom
   FROM mytable a;
```

I want to declare a rule on that view, that I can perform an update operation on `mytable` in order that a newly added polygon gets added to the multipolygon column.

```
CREATE RULE insert_geom_to_myview AS ON INSERT TO myview
    DO instead UPDATE mytable set geom = "add_new_polygon_to_multipolygon"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly recommend using a trigger to work this out - apart from some other things they have less confusing side effects, and can be extended much easier:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_view__instead_of__insert__trigger_function()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
  $$
    BEGIN
      UPDATE mytable
         SET geom = ST_Multi(ST_Union(geom, NEW.geom))
      WHERE  id = NEW.id
      ;

      RETURN NEW;
    END;
  $$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
;

CREATE TRIGGER my_view__instead_of__insert
  INSTEAD OF INSERT ON myview
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_view__instead_of__insert__trigger_function()
;
```

---

**Note:**

This is a minimal trigger implementation: as with any kind of insert handling mechanic you will want to add validity checks, graceful error handling and most of all, a guarantee that you will always update by a single, valid `id` only.

Comment: I get a syntax error executing this: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "TRIGGER"
  Position: 66`

Comment: @Lokomotywa sorry, the `RETURN` statement of a function definition has to follow the signature - I corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

Something using [`st_multi`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Multi.html) should do it:

```
UPDATE mytable set geom = st_multi(polygon);
```

should do it for you.

Comment: I need to merge the new polygon with those which are already part of the multipolygon, so this would most probably not do the job.